# Gradle: How to run a task before and after another one?

Tags: gradle

I'm adding new test platform and I need to start/stop a server for tests.
There is piece of my `build.gradle`:

```
test.dependsOn 'stopAll'
test.dependsOn 'startAll'
test.finalizedBy 'stopAll'
```

I need to run `stopAll` before and after test tests. The test task may be interrupted (Ctrl+C) or crashed and server didn't stop at the end, so I added extra step at the beginning.

Unfortunately, this fails:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:integTest:stopAll
\--- :integTest:test
     \--- :integTest:stopAll (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

How to run `stopAll` before and after the test?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think running the task `stopAll` before your test task will stop the server if the tests are interrupted/crashed. Won't that stop a server that isn't running yet? I suggest that you need to handle that otherwise, eg with a shutdown hook in the server process. Plus, the way Gradle thinks, a task cannot run twice; if you want to do the same thing twice, have two tasks with different names but identical actions.